# How do I achive this exact behavior using divs, rather than using table, tr, and td?

Tags: html, css

In the example code, how do you remove the use of the table, td, and tr tags by replacing them with divs to achieve the same behavior? These behaviors include:

1. content1 text-wraps within column1, when the width of the page is decreased.
2. column2's min-width is the width of its content which in this case is content2 at 120px.

The JSFiddle for this code can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/LwXhE/337/.

Here is the example code:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.column1 {
  width: 65%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.column2 {
  width: 35%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content2 {
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<table class="container">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column1">
        <div class="content1">I am content I am content I am content I am content</div>
      </td>
      <td class="column2">
        <div>
          <div class="content2">Hello Hello</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use CSS `display:table` and `table-row` and `table-cell`

Comment: you can look into http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thank you, using display:table, table-row, and table-cell was the exact solution I needed. Thanks for the link RoR, I do want to learn more about bootstrap. I will study the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS table model:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
}
.column1, .column2 {
  display: table-cell;
}
.column1 {
  width: 65%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.column2 {
  width: 35%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content2 {
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column1">
    <div class="content1">I am content I am content I am content I am content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <div class="content2">Hello Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```